What kind of matrices have eigenvalues lie on complex circle?
Is there a simple characterization for matrices whose complex eigenvalues all have magnitude $R$? Take following matrix as a function of $\theta$:
$$A(\theta)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 10 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) \\
 \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Here's what the eigenvalues look like:

For $\theta$ < 0.84, eigenvalues are real valued, meaning this operation is similar to a diagonal real matrix. So for this point, we can say that this operation is combination of per-dimension scalings in some non-orthogonal coordinate system.
How can we characterize this operation in $0.84 <\theta < 1.91$ range where eigenvalues are complex-valued with fixed magnitude?
Related question

It is unclear to me if you’re speaking about matrices in general or the specific form of matrix you have given. If you are asking for a general classification of matrices whose eigenvalues are a fixed distance from the origin in the complex plane, this seems like an amazingly complex problem. For example, every irreducible matrix representation of a finite group has eigenvalues at unit distance from the origin in the complex plane. It seems unlikely there is some simple classification of these matrices.

[+1] for the animation !

@Qdzyx While the representations are hard to classify, the matrices themselves in any representation of a finite group (or even more generally, torsion group) are easy to classify - they are all similar to unitary matrices. So a combination of rotations and reflections in a possibly non-orthogonal coordinate system, in OP’s way of descriptions. This holds for all diagonalizable matrices whose complex eigenvalues all have modulus $1$. (And modulus $R$ would just be the scaling of those matrices by $R$.)

@DavidGao That is fair. I think the situation is not hopeless like I made it seem. Quite strong things can be said about the matrices of representations! Either way, I think it would be helpful if OP elaborated on what classification they are searching for. The specific function $A(\theta)$ looks to be connected to the matrix representation of cyclic groups. You can actually find that in a question here.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219384/what-are-the-irreducible-representations-of-the-cyclic-group-c-n-over-a-real-v

@Qdzyx The link only mentions the second half of $A(\theta)$. That part’s just a generic rotation matrix. If you insist, it’s a two-dimensional representation of the circle group.

For this specific $A(\theta)$, the behavior can be sort of explained as follows: $A(\theta)$ always have determinant $10$, so it either has two real eigenvalues whose product is $10$, or two imaginary eigenvalues whose product is $10$. In the latter case, as $A(\theta)$ has real entries, the eigenvalues must be conjugate to each other, so they must both have modulus $\sqrt{10}$. As I noted, a diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues have the same complex modulus is, up to a uniform scaling, similar to a unitary matrix. So in this case it’s just saying $A(\theta)$ is either scaling in two…

… different, possibly non-orthogonal direction; or is $\sqrt{10}$ times a rotation w.r.t. a possibly non-orthonormal basis. It’s not surprising that when $\theta$ is near $0$ or $\pi$, you get the first case, since that is exactly what happened at $0$ and $\pi$ - the second term is a scalar matrix, so quantitatively the first term determines the behavior. While near $\pi/2$ you get the second case - the second term is rotation by $\pi/2$, which dominates the behavior. To be precise, it is not hard to check $A(\theta)$ is exactly $\sqrt{10}$ times rotation by $\pi/2$ w.r.t. the non-orthonormal…

… basis ${(1, 0), (0, \sqrt{10})}$. The precise $\theta$ at which the behavior changes needs to be solved by considering the discriminant (which can also prove the intuition that the behavior changes continuously as $\theta$ changes). But I’d say the fact that the behavior changes approximately around $\pi/2$ is hardly a surprise.

@DavidGao thanks, that makes sense. The classification is then 1) real eigenvalues="similar to Hermitian", 2) imaginary="similar to skew-Hermitian", 3) circle="similar to Unitary up to a constant"

@YaroslavBulatov I should note that in all these cases you need to assume the matrices are diagonalizable in the first place. For example, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues that are both real and lie within the unit circle, but it’s similar to neither Hermitian matrices nor unitary matrices.

@YaroslavBulatov Though the generic case is that the eigenvalues are all different and thus the matrix is diagonalizable, so this is not that much of a restriction.
